# Clicking a button with invisible recaptcha but having issue separating token

Tags: python, python-requests, invisible-recaptcha

I am making a script to click a button that has invisible ReCaptcha, I have got to the point where I receive the token however it is also joined by a bunch of extra values which I do not need. I tried to load as a JSON but get errors.

Tried to load as JSON but it would not print

```
import json

with requests.session() as s:

    cap_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LescGEUAAAAAHB01GI2NUqZht8FYV4UWDTMfgtK"

    v= "v1565591531251"
    reason= "q"
    c= "03AOLTBLQhK...."
    hl= "en"
    size= "invisible"
    sa= "vote"
    chr= "[82,3,11]"
    vh= "1391321749"
    bg= "sklfglskfg;lkjdfsg...."

    s.get(cap_url)
    cap_data = dict(v=v, reason=reason, c=c, k=k, co=co, hl=hl, size=size, sa=sa, chr=chr, vh=vh, bg=bg)
    response_cap = s.post(cap_url, data=cap_data, headers={"Referer":"Referer: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LescGEUAAAAAHB01GI2NUqZht8FYV4UWDTMfgtK&co=aHR0cHM6Ly8xLnNob3J0c3RhY2suY29tOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=v1565591531251&size=invisible&cb=mac9os912hh0", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"})
    print(response_cap.text)
```

It prints

```
["rresp","03AOLTBLTxihRmz5TITehHp-5ElsA_q_IpfAmHV4UagO-2rNfoHWp5CJZ2rSm2fiMZziCQRJRB54uVtSg3ZvM3m-7yrzpSeE977wmJEdtDfznduOj81oRic4tQQDJu86wsd20LUP5SkBUeyRo3EpZLepEfExLW3KnAsQGihp7JVJOoqWTWivRxXAYFkJ5FqbByyU8usrfP23MUY3iA32aCMVoWskKAaL3fJVZ91Sst0mGgBY5K9h6VBGPDNOOpvHtu-4EF1zSvh0OlCS0641ZElJPWi2_d7bf-5nMGl-oT8gQgJtnPcpBh62VARN52jXkJDHwikB4CVuA1g2vuZ0htMcEegmDQOrP0aQO0AjZeAIKU3m3g3CsTvO43uIAEKKvBWzgxvP7qgEY-",null,120,null,null,null,["bgdata","Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9qcy9iZy9wV21nVGJ6clY3..."]      
,"05AHVohkZt...."]
```

(... is in place of alot of extra text)

I just need the token at the start, in this case

```
03AOLTBLTxihRmz5TITehHp-5ElsA_q_IpfAmHV4UagO-2rNfoHWp5CJZ2rSm2fiMZziCQRJRB54uVtSg3ZvM3m-7yrzpSeE977wmJEdtDfznduOj81oRic4tQQDJu86wsd20LUP5SkBUeyRo3EpZLepEfExLW3KnAsQGihp7JVJOoqWTWivRxXAYFkJ5FqbByyU8usrfP23MUY3iA32aCMVoWskKAaL3fJVZ91Sst0mGgBY5K9h6VBGPDNOOpvHtu-4EF1zSvh0OlCS0641ZElJPWi2_d7bf-5nMGl-oT8gQgJtnPcpBh62VARN52jXkJDHwikB4CVuA1g2vuZ0htMcEegmDQOrP0aQO0AjZeAIKU3m3g3CsTvO43uIAEKKvBWzgxvP7qgEY-
```

**EDIT: just tried**

`res = json.loads(response_cap.text)`
    print(res[1])

THAT PRINTS:

````
File "vote.py", line 24, in <module>
    res = json.loads(response_cap.text)
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```
````

Comment: do you have to use ```json```? If it's a one-time thing just use regex: import ```re``` and add ```print(re.search('rresp","(.*?)"', response_cap.text).group(1))```

Comment: How to generate `v` , `c` , `vh` ,`bg` ,`chr` parameters ?

Comment: What even are those parameters? You may have to give more information like where you would normally get them in the first place, and perhaps extract them from the source

Comment: @Xosrov can you show me an Document about `v` , `c` , `vh` ,`bg` ,`chr` ?

Answer (score 0):

the response is in Byte, so try this:

```
captcha_response = response_cap.content
captcha_response = captcha_response.decode('latin-1')
captcha_response = captcha_response[15:477] #adjust numbers to display only the captcha
```

now could you tell me how you clicked on the invisible recaptcha and how did you get the body that should be sent? Because i'm try to take a valide g-recaptcha-response too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I gave up on that as its not actually a bypass of such. You are best to use a 3rd party and use the token they send. EG 2captcha

Comment: How do you take the data information to send in the request?

Comment: Its not needed, just use the sitekey and request from 2captcha using that and the site url